# Sublime Text 3 Gulp Package

Tags: node.js, sublimetext3, gulp

I'm new to both Sublime and Gulp…I'm trying to install the sublime-gulp package into Sublime Text 3.

After a bunch of wrangling to get the package to see Node on my system (finally solved by installing the "SublimeFixMacPath" package).

The package is installed in Sublime and I'm in a folder in Sublime where I have Gulp installed and working from the command line, but when I run the "Gulp" command from the Command Palette I'm getting this error message:

"SublimeGulp: There was an error running gulp.
Make sure gulp is running correctly in your project."

I feel like I'm probably missing something basic here, but have double-checked my $PATH and $NODE_PATHs, reinstalled both the global and local copies of npm and gulp (and all my gulp modules) but it's still not working.

Comment: Can't get it work myself on w8, same error as you. But works fine in command line. If you are new, you better have to use Gulp in command line first to get how it works.

Comment: Hello!, I created the package. If you run gulp from the terminal in your project, it works fine?, Inspired by your question I just added a log to see the errors, you could take a look there. Remember that you can open an issue in github.com/NicoSantangelo/sublime-gulp

Comment: Nico, the log helped me figure it out. For some reason, the Sublime Text package installer wasn't installing the resources for your package. I did a manual install and all is working fine now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad I could help!, thanks for giving me the idea for the log.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the answer is in the comments: "I did a manual install and all is working fine now."

Comment: Hi!, the author of the package again. Actually this is fixed now, with the help of @Evan-Cobalt2 I realized that I was missing a `.no-sublime-package` file in the package :).